# Проблема с установкой nginx на убунту

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Проблема с установкой nginx на убунту.

По ссылке `php.x/index.nginx-debian.html`:

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed
>   and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
>   Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

php.x
Так видны все файлы как в апаче `/etc/nginx/sites-available/php.x`:

```
server {

charset utf-8;
server_name php.x;
set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

access_log /var/log/nginx/php.x-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/php.x-error.log;
root /var/www/php.x;
index $yii_bootstrap;

set $htdocs /var/www/php.x;

location / {

# Redirect everything that isn't real file to yii bootstrap file including arguments.
try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
}

include /etc/nginx/_location_php;
```

После  обновления конфигов:

```
nginx -s reload
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2019/12/30 15:55:53 [warn] 20919#20919: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2019/12/30 15:55:53 [notice] 20919#20919: signal process started
2019/12/30 15:55:53 [error] 20919#20919: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Для начала `sudo nginx -s reload`

Comment: sudo nginx -s reload

nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Comment: ls -la
итого 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     adm    4096 дек 30 14:38 .
drwxrwxr-x 15 root     syslog 4096 дек 30 14:40 ..
-rw-r-----  1 www-data adm       0 дек 30 14:17 access.log
-rw-r-----  1 www-data adm    1197 дек 30 16:23 error.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      0 дек 30 14:38 php.x-access.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      0 дек 30 14:38 php.x-error.log

Comment: <code>Активные соединения с интернетом (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      930/memcached       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1100/apache2        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979/nginx: master p 
</code>
почему-то при смене порта апач не работает